# Creating Parametrized Classes in a Visio UML

Tags: microsoft-visio, microsoft-visio-2010, uml

Let's say I have a class defined like this

```
public class Widget<T1, T2, T3>
    where T1 : ISomeInterface<T2, T3>
    where T2 : class
    where T3 : struct
{
    // blah
}
```

Using Visio 2010 I've created a parametrized template and set `T1, T2, T3` as the parameters, but how do I set the type of each type? If I select the type dropdown I have c#, c++, VB and IDL primitives to choose from, but not any of the classes or interfaces I have already defined. Not do I have 'standard' types like 'class' and 'struct'.

Can anyone tell me what I'm missing please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer, appears to be, you don't, or not at least as far as I can see.

In Visio 2013, however, you can enter what you want as now the shapes on a UML diagram are just that, shapes.

There is no modelling going on at all, so you an entry what you want where you want it.